# android: how to resize dialog

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I would like to create a dialog-style form which would fill the bigger screen area (left, right, top, bottom padding 10px).

I defined the style "CupCakeDialog" the following way:

```
<style name="CupcakeDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
</style>
```

and by running the activity:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

setContentView(R.layout.ad_popup);
```

The dialog is displayed the following way:

[alt text http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/1299/popupstackoverflow.png](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/1299/popupstackoverflow.png)

Does anyone know how to make the dialog bigger (extend height)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're providing a custom layout for the dialog, you should just be able to provide top and bottom padding as normal around the text.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, I am late, but the answer is here.

```
dialog.show();

Display display =((WindowManager)getSystemService(context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height=display.getHeight();

    Log.v("width", width+"");
dialog.getWindow().setLayout((6*width)/7,(4*height)/5);
```

Change height or width, whatever is needed...

Comment: Can I give you some money Sir. This is the best answer. Thank You very much !

Comment: Appreciation is enough sir.

Answer (score 1):

For Dialogs/AlertDialogs inside a DialogFragment, you should resize the window in `DialogFragment.onStart()`; especially if using AppCompat support library 23.2.1 or 24 or above.

See here for example: [How to resize an AlertDialog.Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777584/how-to-resize-an-alertdialog-builder/#48015852)