# kotlin - custom font to alertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I must change default font of `alertDialog.setMessage` and `alertDialog.setTitle` but I can't use a custom layout, so I have to change it by code in **Kotlin**.
I tried using typeface, but he doesn't detect the font in `res/font/product_sans_bold.ttf`

I also used

```
content.text = Html.fromHtml(resources.getString(R.string.centripetaFormule))
content.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(applicationContext, R.font.product_sans_bold)
alertDialog.setView(content)
```

and it works, but not as i want.

I have a string

```
<string name ="centripetaFormule>![CDATA[<h5>(...)</h5><p>(...)</p>
```

where `h5` is bold, so using variable content there will be no differences between h5 and "normal" text, except for the size.

So, I want to change font just for normal text, I can't use a custom layout, I have to use strings with `CDATA`.

How to do that?

Hope I explained it well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom font for alert dialog in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051956/how-to-set-custom-font-for-alert-dialog-in-android) or [Multiple TypeFace in single TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10675070/6334037)

Answer (score 0):

Android comes with a nice default font but in some cases you might want to use a different font.

Fastest Way to use custom font android

**Put your font file in asset folder**

[image]

**Create Typeface Object**

```
 Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf")
```

**Set Typeface to TextView/EditText/Button etc…**

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
textView.setTypeface(customFont);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that i have an Header and a "normal" text and they must have different fonts, so this method doesn't works well

Answer (score 0):

I get around the problem like this :

Customize the view

dialog_custom_nunito.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/custom_dialog_tv" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_margin="12sp"
              android:textSize="18sp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/warning_recherche_no_found"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Kotlin Code :

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_custom_nunito)
builder.setNegativeButton("OK") { dialogInterface, i -> }
                    builder.show()
```

I hope it will help other people,