# How to resize an AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: android, resize, android-alertdialog

I'd like to resize my `AlertDialog.Builder` but I didn't find any resolution on this website, I tried everything I saw on questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406804/how-to-control-the-width-and-height-of-default-alert-dialog-in-android) but seems older than I'm looking for, The code I'm watching doesn't work right now...

**ALERTDIALOGBUILDER.JAVA**

```
public class AlertDialogInfo extends AlertDialog.Builder {

public AlertDialogInfo(Context context, String title, String msg) {
    super(context);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(msg);
    builder.setNegativeButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

I tried to become `AlertDialog.Builder` to `AlertDialog` to resize it, but just displays a black square without data.

**QUESTION**: What should I do to make an AlertDialog.Builder with a large text? (need to scroll that sure, because I don't want to make the dialog as big as my screen)

**UPDATED**:

What I want is something like this, I HAVE TO CHANGE THE TEXT by `Bundle`, I call the AlertDialog from my AppCompatActivity which uses `FrameLayout` (I don't know what kind of Dialog it should be to cover what I need):

[image: WhatIWant]

**UPDATED 2**:

Finally I've been trying to do what I'm looking for with the next code, but it still doesn't work...

**ALERT_DIALOG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="250dp">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MYALERTDIALOG.JAVA**

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String text) {
    MyDialogFragment frag = new MyDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("TEXT", text);
    System.out.print("Text dentro de newInstance: " + text);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String sinopsis = getArguments().getString("TEXT");
    System.out.print("Text dentro de onCreateDialog: " + text);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setTitle("TITLE")
            .setMessage(text)
            .setNegativeButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            ) .create();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, container);
}
}
```

**ActivityWhereDialogIsBeenCalled.java**

```
........
DialogFragment frag = MyDialogFragment.newInstance("MY MESSAGE");
        frag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"TAG");
...............
```

My dialog appears using DEFAULT LAYOUT (It doesn't have scrollview nor my interested size (just shows as default android alert dialog...)

How can I resolve this question? I think that's silly, but it's frustating... Thanks anyway!

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because .

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom dialog layout, check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout).

Actually, you can resize dialog by `getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);` just call it onResume (not onCreateView).

Your view must be nested inside of a ScrollView, check [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955053/android-how-do-i-make-this-alert-dialog-scrollable).

Reading huge amount of text in a Dialog can be annoying, it's better to use all pixels you have, consider simple Activity/Fragment.

Comment: Thanks you Maxim, could you tell me how to make not fullscreen a DialogFragment? It seems the same error...

Comment: I already saw this post, and seems to be what I'm looking for, thanks. But what's the best way to change the message of the dialog using Bundle since the Activity where Dialog is calling??

Comment: Same as for any Fragment, [repo link](https://github.com/mgolokhov/dodroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/doit/study/droid/DislikeDialog.java#L22)

Comment: I tried dislikedialog... but cannot shrink my dialog fragment... It is still filling as large as text be

Answer (score -1):

If you're using an AlertDialog within a DialogFragment, with the [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7-appcompat) support library 23.2.1 or above, you must put the resize code in **`DialogFragment.onStart()`**, otherwise it will not work. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Method 1
    alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().width = 400; // pixels
    alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().height = 500; // pixels
    // Re-apply the modified attributes
    alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(
           alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    
    // Method 2 (alternative)
    alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(400, 500); // size in pixels
}
```

More info:

- [AlertDialog with custom view: Resize to wrap the view's content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907104/alertdialog-with-custom-view-resize-to-wrap-the-views-content)